# All files and folders in the root partition are deleted by unknown reason

Tags: nginx, debian

I have a Debian box with nginx webserver, hosting a webmail interface. The server worked fine for a a while. Today I started to get 404 errors when pointing to home page.
All of the files on the root partition are missing, except nginx log folder and files ( /var/logs/nginx) that are newly created. Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:** Please note that all the files and folders in / are gone. No history or log exists. nginx logs just record the 404 errors of deleted pages.

Comment: Reinstall and restore your backups.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I did so, but I'd like to understand and prevent the problem. While all the files and folders in / are gone, how can I log or report the sequence of related events and actions?

Comment: You can't. With all files gone there is nothing you can do. If you want to be prepared when this happens again,  configure your logging system to send the logs to another machine.